# R: place of min / max in a matrix

Tags: r, find, max, min

I have a table of 10 variables and 193 observations (10 columns and 193 rows)

now I found for each column the min/max with

```
#min
minINT <- apply(INT, 1, min)

#max
maxINT <- apply(INT, 1, max)
```

How can I find now the "place" of the min/max value in each row?
(e.g. row 1 = 3 variable ; or row 156 = 7 variable)

Thanks!

Comment: `apply(INT, 1, which.min)`

Comment: Commenters, please post these comments as answers ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You contradict yourself in your question: is it the maximum in each row or in each column that you want? I assume in the following that you want the maximum per row, since this is what your code is doing.

`which.min()` and `which.max()` return the position of the minimum and maximum of a vector, respectively. You can use them with `apply()`:

```
#min
minINT_pos <- apply(INT, 1, which.min)

#max
maxINT_pos <- apply(INT, 1, which.max)
```

If there is a tie, that is, if several elements take the maximum or minimum value, this will return the position of the first of these elements (thanks to [Richard Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/richard-scriven) for the comment).

There is also the funtion `max.col()` that returns the index of the maximum in each row.

```
maxINT_pos <- max.col(INT)
```

This function differs from `which.max()` in that you can specify what is done in the case of a tie. By default, it picks on of the values randomly, but you can also set `ties.method = "first"` or `ties.method = "last"` to pick the first (as does `which.max()`) or the last element.

In addition, `max.col()` is faster than `which.max()` with `apply()`:

```
library(microbenchmark)
m <- matrix(runif(1000), ncol = 10)
microbenchmark(apply(m, 1, which.max), max.col(m))
## Unit: microseconds
##                    expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval cld
##  apply(m, 1, which.max) 190.883 200.7075 230.56125 211.5590 223.3115 529.712   100   b
##              max.col(m)  53.316  57.0905  69.54417  61.3835  71.2555 204.897   100  a
```

`min.col()` does not exist, but you can easily get the minima by multiplying the matrix by -1 (thanks to [nicola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987294/nicola) for the hint):

```
minINT_pos <- max.col(-INT)
```

Comment: `which(x == max(x))` would give you positions of all, should there be any  ties.

Comment: `min.col<-function(m,...) max.col(-m,...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments.